# Filter Then Sort Results By Query in ElasticSearch

Tags: sorting, search, elasticsearch

Is there a way in ElasticSearch to run a boolean filter, then without refinding the search further, sort/order the results based on a multi_field query?

Eg: Get all items with `status_id = 1` (the filter), then order those documents by using the keywords "red car" (documents whose `name` and `description` contain those keywords are first, documents without are last).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bool query - 
As per condition of should -

> The clause (query) should appear in the matching document. In a boolean query with no must clauses, one or more should clauses must match a document. The minimum number of should clauses to match can be set using the minimum_should_match parameter.

In our case , as there is a must and its a number match , score value wont be computed. But then conditions in should would be used for computing the score alone -

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "status_id": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "red car",
            "fields": [
              "subject",
              "message"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I was actually doing this, minus one thing, I was doing the 'must' as part of a filter, not the query. As a result, the should was by itself, and was reducing the result set.